# OpenAI function call returns with an errror

Tags: openai-api, velo

I have tried everything but for some reason my API call to OpenAI return with an error saying no API Key found. Here is my code:

```
// Function to create chat completion using OpenAI fetch API
export const createChatCompletionAI = async (prompt) => {
  const url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
  const apiKey = await getSecret("OPENAI_API_KEY");
  const body = {
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "prompt": prompt,
    "max_tokens": 500,
    "temperature": 0.8,
  }
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : `Bearer ${apiKey}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };

  const response = await fetch(url,options);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

I am getting the following error from OpenAI: "You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from [https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys."](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.%22)
type: "invalid_request_error"

I see that I am passing an API Key in the header but I am clearly missing something. Any help or our pointers in the right direction would be helpful.
Cheers,

Comment: Please ignore above question. I had a typo "header" instead if "headers".